# Merging two dataframes and dispaying result Dataframe column by column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

When merging Df1 with Df2 that have same columns [A B C] on KEY I get this result:

```
KEY      A_x  B_x  C_x  A_y  B_y  C_y
```

I would like to have this:

```
KEY   A_x  A_y  B_x  B_y  C_x  C_y
```

I am using merge function:

```
    df_result= pd.merge(df_old,df_new, how='left', on='KEY')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the order of columns in your dataframe with:

```py
df.columns = ['A_x', 'A_y', 'B_x', 'B_y', 'C_x', 'C_y']
```

Comment: this will not sort but  assign the column name with this list , `df.columns = ['A_x', 'A_y', 'B_x', 'B_y', 'C_x', 'C_y']` is different from `df[['A_x', 'A_y', 'B_x', 'B_y', 'C_x', 'C_y']]`

Comment: This will work as long as the number of columns in the dataframe is the same as the length of your list

Comment: what i mean is it will rename `B_x` to `A_y` , instead of sorting

Comment: I have many more columns in my dataframe , I was looking for something in the function

Comment: @Khaled did you try the `sort=True` option on `pd.merge`?